# SDL_GL_SwapWindow crashes upon third call

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have made a very basic SDL application which kept going for a few iterations of the main loop, but then crashed. I have located the error to lie in *SDL_GL_SwapWindow*, which works the first two times, then crashes. This is a very simplified version that I have actually tried and it did the same thing.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Window* SDLWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Balls", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_GLContext SDLGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(SDLWindow);
glewInit();

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDLWindow);
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDLWindow);
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDLWindow); //crashes here

return 0;
```

**First two calls work just fine, the third one crashes the program.** Strangely, the crash occured in *igd10umd32.dll* and the debugger didn't allow me to read that file. I looked that up on the internet, but no attempts to fix the library worked. Besides, if the problem was in this library, it probably wouldn't appear under such strange conditions.

And what's even weirder is that the program works fine on my second laptop. And when I compiled it there and ran it on this laptop, it also worked fine.

I'm using Windows 10. I've worked with SDL/OpenGL many times and never encountered anything like this. Any ideas what may cause this very chaotic behavior?

Comment: *igd10umd32.dll* is part of the graphics driver. It's quite likely that your version of SDL is doing something wrong and causing the crash. Have you tried this executable on a different graphics adapter/machine? What version of SDL are you using? What libraries are you linking with?

Comment: @ananthonline: Unlikely. SDL_GL_SwapWindow is a extremely simple codepath. Also a quick Google for that DLL indicates that it's caught up in crashes a lot (also high profile programs like MS Office). I'd say this is a driver bug.

Comment: I begin with suspecting my code first and then move on to suspecting the driver. I'm no Carmack :) In any case, the OP should try running other OpenGL test applications. If they work then this an issue with the codepath the application is taking (driver and/or user code)

Comment: @ananthonline I just upgraded my SDL from 2.0.3 to 2.0.4. No difference. All other OpenGL apps work fine. And when I compiled it here, it didn't work on the other computer, but when it got compiled there, it worked on this one. I'm using nothing but SDL, SDL_image and glew.

Comment: Are you using the same compiler (name, version and OS of both computers please)? Could you post the *full* compiler command line used to generate the executable? I'm suspecting the compiler/C++ runtime now.

Comment: Just a thought - if you're running this on a machine with Optimus (Nvidia + Intel GPUs), try explicitly running this program only on the Nvidia GPU (using the Nvidia control panel).

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and Windows 10 on both computers, but the problem appears to be something with the graphics drivers, since it crashes with NVIDIA, but works with Integrated graphics (Intel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was nothing more than an NVIDIA bug. Updating the driver got rid of all problems.

Comment: It is quite unlikely that a crash in the _intel_ drivers is NVIDIA's fault. It might be the case that you were using your integrated GPU before, and now you are using a discrete one, but that insn't actually a fix for the original issue then.